# I can't open my Excel file on python, using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, import

I can't open my Excel file on python, and I think I've tried all the options out there.

I am using a mac, and I don't think I typed in the path wrong..? I've installed `xlrd` and `openpyxl` as well, but I don't think it's the reader problem...

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.ExcelFile("/User/[username]/desktop/assignment3/titanic3.xls")
```

and I get this error:

[image]

Comment: you're passing `/User/[username]/desktop/assignment3/titanic3.xls` literaly? but does this path exist on your system? with the square brackets???

Answer (score 4):

You should replace `[username]` with your real username.

To get your username, enter `whoami` in a terminal (Not python, but a shell terminal).

To open a terminal on Mac OS X, type <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to open Spotlight, then type `terminal` to open a terminal.

Then replace the returned value of `whoami` in your jupyter command.

From what I have seen, it should be `cynthiaoh`

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.ExcelFile("/User/cynthiaoh/Desktop/assignment3/titanic3.xls")
```

If this does not work, it means:

- you have a camel case problem: is it `desktop` or `Desktop`
- the `Excel` file you want to load is not located in the directory you think it is.

Comment: I don't know who voted you down, it looks like a good answer, I am reversing it with a vote up

Comment: @UriGoren, same here, it looks like a correct answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
pd.read_excel(r'file_path.xls')
```